# Добавление данных в массив

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый вечер.
Что я имею:
Объявил массив

```
int[] indexes = new int[countOfElements];
```

Как в c# реализовать автозаполнение массива, т.е.

если я делаю нечто похожее на 
`indexes = 5;`
то последней незаполненной ячейке присваивается 5.

Спасибо.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под *"незаполненной ячейкой"* в массиве, состоящем из объектов `non-nullable value` типа?

Comment: в вашем случае

    indexes = 5;

у вас не получиться, разве что вы релизуете собственную коллекуию на основе `int[]` и переопределите `implicit operator`

Comment: Допустим, int[] indexes = new int[countOfElements];

в indexes[0] мы ничего не помещали.

Так вот в случае присваивания, чтобы автоматически записалось в нулевую ячейку, потом в первую и т.д.

Comment: может вам нужен `List<int>`?

    var list = new List<int>(countOfElements);
    list.Add(5);
    list[0] // 5

Comment: А на c# C с массивами такое не работает?

Comment: >> А на c# с массивами такое не работает?

А в каком языке такое работает?

Comment: ну, например в php.

Comment: Я думаю автор имел в виду indexes[] = 5 и растёт это из php.

Comment: Да, но только это не работает =)

Comment: Что именно не работает? Если Вы хотите использовать динамичный массив - используйте generic List. Перегрузка оператора `=` в C# запрещена идеологически. У Вас цель какая? Сделать C# похожим на php?

Comment: @Spectre: опубликуете идею с `Add` как ответ? Это именно то, что хотел ТС: добавить новый элемент в конец.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Также, если Вы хотите добавлять новый элемент через оператор `=` то можно пойти таким кривым путём:

Создать класс например тупо отнаследовавшись от List<int> и объявить свойство которое будет добавлять элемент в него. Не хотите лист а именно массив тоже можно так:

```
class MyDummyArray{
  private int[] _currentArray = new int[];
  public int[] items_array { get { return _currentArray;} }
  public int items { 
    set{ 
      var oldArray = new int[_currentArray.Length+1]; 
      //Тут надо написать код который перенесёт данные из _currentArray в oldArray, Спасибо @Spectre
      _currentArray = oldArray;
      _currentArray[_currentArray.Length-1] = value;
    }
}

...

var myArray = new MyDummyArray();
myArray.items = 5;
myArray.items = 6;
//myArray.items_array == int[5,6]
```

Comment: мне кажется

    _currentArray = new int[_currentArray.Length+1];

уничтожит все ранее сохранённые данные

Comment: Да, Ваша правда. Надо ещё перенос данных добавить. Но думаю идея и так понятна. А писать пол первого ночи правильный код кривой дорожки... Такой код вообще стыдно писать в прикладных целях :-)